# How to rotate a 2D Array anticlockwise by 45º Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to rotate a 2d array by 45º so I can be able to split it and run the split array on 2 threads. Basically the input looks like this

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

And the output should look like this
3
2 6
1 5 9
4 8
7

Comment: Have you tried solving it? Are you stuck on your attempt? If so, show your code and we can try to help.

Comment: I tried solving it but after a while I realized I didn't know what I was doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that difficult. Like always in programming you need to have an idea what you want to do. Lets look at your example.

You start with the last number of the first row of your matrix. It is the 3.
**Rotating by 45° means, you go down one row and right one column.** This is out of bounds and the first line is done (you can add a line-feed).

Then you move to the next number in the first row which is before 3. That is the 2.
You rotate as written above and get the 6. This is the last number of this line and you add the line-feed).

You iterate till the first number of the first row and then you take all starting numbers of the rows and do the same like above. This gives us for the third line the numbers 1, 5 and 9.

A code to solve this could be like this:

```
static int[][] matrix;

public static void printLine(Point p) {
    // this solves the one row down, one column right algorithm
    try {
        for (int i3=p.x; i3<matrix[0].length; i3++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i3][p.y++]);
        }
    } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {}   // stops, when last number in row is reached
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    matrix = new int[][] { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9} };

    // the two iterations

    for (int i1=matrix[0].length-1; i1>0; i1--) {
        printLine(new Point(0, i1));
    }
    for (int i2=0; i2<matrix.length; i2++) {
        printLine(new Point(i2,0));
    }        
}
```

PS: Surely we could calculate the bounds of the array correctly and without try-catch, but you get the idea behind it.